# mysqli connect() i get an error message when using IP address

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, localhost

I pulled this directly off php.net

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "database", 3306);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
```

my output is like so:

Localhost via UNIX socket

My question is... why am i getting an error message when i try to use the second method.

> Failed to connect to MySQL: (1045) Access denied for user '*****'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)

Comment: This question doesn't show *any* research effort.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that skip-networking is commented out in your conig file. Also look into your users table and see if "user" is allowed to connect from 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal and type: (login as root user)

```
mysql -i -u root
```

Let’s start by making a new user within the MySQL shell (if you do not have (*) user at 127.0.0.1 host):

```
CREATE USER '*'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Then you've to type the following: (give (*) user permission to access database)

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO '*'@'127.0.0.1';
```

Once you have finalized the permissions that you want to set up for your new users, always be sure to reload all the privileges:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Your changes will now be in effect.

How To Grant Different User Permissions
Here is a short list of other common possible permissions that users can enjoy.

ALL PRIVILEGES- as we saw previously, this would allow a MySQL user all access to a designated database (or if no database is selected, across the system)

- CREATE- allows them to create new tables or databases
- DROP- allows them to them to delete tables or databases
- DELETE- allows them to delete rows from tables
- INSERT- allows them to insert rows into tables
- SELECT- allows them to use the Select command to read through
  databases
- UPDATE- allow them to update table rows
- GRANT OPTION- allows them to grant or remove other users' privileges

  **Reference**

> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql